# rspec: undefined method 'latest'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec2, rspec-rails

I am testing a single method in the model. It's called `last_photo`, I filled in the data of the database and try to return the first element, but I have an error `udefined method 'latest'`. What could it be? How can I fix it?

Method `latest` this:
    scope :latest, -> { order('created_at DESC') }

```
def last_photo
  @last_photo ||= user_updates.latest.where("photo_front IS NOT NULL and photo_front != ''").first.try(:photo_front)
end

context "instance method" do
  let(:user) { create :user }

  context "last photo" do
    before { create_list(:user_update, 3, user: user) }
    let(:user_updates){ UserUpdate.all }

    describe "#last_photo" do
      subject { user.last_photo }

      it { should eq user_updates.latest.first.photo_front }
    end

    describe "#last_photo_side" do
      subject { user.last_photo_side }

      it { should eq user_updates.latest.first.photo_side}
    end
  end
end
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I bet `UserUpdate.all` returns an array. So you cant chain scopes on it.

Replace with:

```
let(:user_updates){ UserUpdate.scoped }
```

Comment: Yes, exactly, thank you. I have another question. How here use the `where` method?

Comment: I dont understand what you mean

Comment: `where("photo_front IS NOT NULL and photo_front != ''")` as in the tests to use?

Comment: I'd say: make it a scope and use the scope in your spec